# How Can I create Webfont?

Tags: website-design

How can I create webfont? any software or online service which can create webfont from my custom TrueType font.

Comment: Is that "custome" in your question supposed to be "custom" or "customer"? (Or something else.) Could you edit to fix?

Comment: I fix it, custom font is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options. You could use an industry standard such as FontLab Studio which is indeed expensive or other freeware alternatives:

- [Font Struct](http://fontstruct.com/)
- [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/)
- BitFontMaker2

Answer (score 2):

Font Squirrel has a [free service](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) you can use to format an existing font for embedded use.

Comment: @Ashian however DO note that you often need a special license to use fonts on the web.

Comment: This is true, though I'd assumed the "custom[e]" in the question meant the asker actually *owned* the font in question. (Unless that's a typo for "customer?")