# Use of rare fonts on the web

Tags: css, fonts

I have just been peeking at the source code of a web page.

I notice that there is a CSS rule that defines what seems to be a rare font for some nice-looking subheadings.

Html ([Source file](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/go-agile-release-management-landing-page/more-about-go?&referrer=70150000000K580&gclid=CKa9h9P40LQCFcjKtAodRUkAow))

```
<h2><em><span style="color:#333">Model your workflow to fail fast.</span></em></h2>
```

CSS ([source file](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/sites/default/files/css/css_876fcb70024fbcf49e8bb6a670d305cd.css))

```
...

h2 em {
    font-family: MarydaleBold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
}
...
```

I am interested to know how it is possible to use a rare font like that for distribution over the web to many computers that may not have that font installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're using [font embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_embedding_on_the_Web), through [TypeKit](https://typekit.com/). This can also be accomplished locally by using your own properly-formatted font files, either by converting them with desktop font creation software or services such as font Squirrel (cf. [previous question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/how-can-i-create-webfont)), though you'll have to pay close attention to your font licensing to see if that's allowed. But it can be convoluted, and TypeKit just makes it easier plus has arrangements with many foundries who disallow it to distribute their fonts for such use.

[Marydale](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/singles/three_islands_press/marydale_regular/) itself isn't in TypeKit's regular library, but is licensed from FontShop, and then [transferred](http://blog.fontshop.com/2012/07/09/buyers-guide-can-all-webfonts-be-linked-to-typekit/) for use through TypeKit.

Answer (score 3):

Google also provides free access to many fonts:

https://developers.google.com/webfonts/

I'm currently using Google's fonts in developing the next iteration of my company's website.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I didn't know about that service from Google.